# string split pipe not working in Mirth connect JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mirth

I have tried to split a pipe from a string in Mirth connect JavaScrip, but for some reason, it's not working as expecting.

Example:

```
var x = "RO|123|test|account|test2";
var arr = x.split('|');
```

I expecting the output when I loop through the variable arr as below:

```
arr[0] -> RO
arr[1] -> 123
arr[2] -> test
arr[3] -> account
arr[4] -> test2
```

BUT for some reason the output is as below:

```
arr[0] -> R
arr[1] -> O
arr[2] -> |
arr[3] -> 1
arr[4] -> 2
```

Does anyone know why and how could I solve this issue?

Comment: can you produce a minimal running example of this ? maybe on codepen, or stackblitz ? because the posted code should work fine,

Comment: it is coming as expected https://jsfiddle.net/083dvbnh/

Answer (score 5):

In your actual code, x is probably a Java string, and not a Javascript string like in your example. The Java String.split method takes a regex string as the first parameter.

For this declaration:

```
var x = new java.lang.String("RO|123|test|account|test2");
```

Either of these should give the expected result:

```
// Calling the Java String.split method.
var arr = x.split('\\|'); // arr will be a Java array

// Explicitly convert to a Javascript string to ensure calling
// Javascript String.prototype.split function.
var arr = String(x).split('|'); // arr will be a Javascript array
```

Note: For those that only picked up on the javascript tag, mirth javascript runs in a Mozilla Rhino environment.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine as it is working as expected.

```js
var x = "RO|123|test|account|test2";
var arr = x.split('|');
/* document.write(arr); */

for(var i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
 document.write("arr["+[i]+"] ->"+arr[i]+ "<br>");
}
```